# GoogleVis Orgchart with additional text

Tags: r, google-visualization, rstudio, visualization, googlevis

GoogleVis Orgchart from example [image: example]

My Need (i.e add additional information to the nodes, such as President in the example)

[image]

My try, with help from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/).

```
library(googleVis)
Org <- gvisOrgChart(idvar = {v:goo$Region, f:goo$Val} , parentvar = goo$Parent, tipvar = goo$Val,
                    options=list(allowHtml=TRUE, width=600, height=250,
                                 size='large', allowCollapse=TRUE))
plot(Org)
```

But not working, any help? I plan to use this in shinydashboard.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily add addition information with [GetOrgChart](http://www.getorgchart.com/)

[image]

Here is an example:

```js
$("#people").getOrgChart({
  primaryColumns: ["name", "title"],
  dataSource: [{
      id: 1,
      parentId: null,
      name: "Mike",
      title: "President"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      parentId: 1,
      name: "Jim",
      title: "Vice President"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      parentId: 1,
      name: "Alice"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      parentId: 2,
      name: "Bob"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      parentId: 4,
      name: "Carol"
    }

  ]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#people {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="people"></div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but I need it in R, that were GoogleVis package comes in.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you

https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart.html

just modify dataScource according to your need it will display all content that you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Organization Chart Plugin</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.orgchart.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #chart-container { text-align: right; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    var datascource = {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
            { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer' }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' }
      ]
    };

    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'data' : datascource,
      'nodeContent': 'title',
      'direction': 'r2l'
    });

  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thankyou